# React Native Tooltip - Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In my react-native project, I am using the following tooltip library.

https://github.com/jasongaare/react-native-walkthrough-tooltip

I'm using the Tooltip as follows:

```
            <Tooltip
              isVisible={showGuide}
              content={renderTT()}
              placement="center"
              onClose={() => console.log('closed')}
            ><View><Text>Here</Text></View>
            </Tooltip>
```

The renderTT() function returns a view for the tooltip and also sets the state of showGuide to false - setShowGuide(false).

renderTT() looks something like this:

```
  const renderTT = props => {
    setShowGuide(false)
    return (
      <View style={{padding:10}}>
        <Text>This is tooltip</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

The problem happens when I navigate to another screen or previous screen. It shows a warning as follows pointing to this line in my screen:

`Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.`

Can you please help with why this is happening and how I can resolve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Just need some more clarification, are you doing any setState() in componentDidMount()?

Comment: How does this work, so you're rendering the tooltip if showGuide is true, but when it's rendering you're setting the showGuide to false? I don't thing the `setShowGuide` belongs in the content of your Tooltip, can you move it away from there?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/jasongaare/react-native-walkthrough-tooltip/issues/113

https://github.com/jasongaare/react-native-walkthrough-tooltip/issues/93

It looks like your issue is coming from a setTimeout inside the tooltip class.

https://github.com/jasongaare/react-native-walkthrough-tooltip/pull/105

It also looks like it's being addressed and possibly merging a solution for that. You can check if it is your error by adding that code to your local project and seeing if the error disappears. But it looks like it will be fixed soon!